# Getting the coordinates of the complete street from Maps

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I am working on a project for traffic data collection. Is there any way to mark the complete street given the street name in google maps and retreive all the coordinates on that street.
I tried looking on but couldn't get any relevant method. So is there any better alternative then the manually collecting the coordinates.

Comment: The google directions api allows you to create a route, which is what you are asking for I believe. [route creation api](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/directions/)

Comment: I wanted to mark or color a street given the street name and extract its coordinates where it is present ( Including all points from starting to the ending coordinates of the street)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply manually enter the coordinate of the polyline:http://build-failed.blogspot.de/2013/07/dynamically-creating-hexagons-from-real.html?m=1.